# Returning to Germany after de-registration and applying for PR

Tags: germany, resident-permit

I worked in Germany for 4 years on Blue Card, paying taxes etc, didn't get PR (Niederlassungserlaubnis), found new job in UK, de-registered and left the country for 2 years. Blue Card naturally expired as >5years passed since.

Now wanna return to Germany, I already found a job there and can get work visa.

As I've already contributed taxes for 33 months, can I immediately apply for PR/Niederlassungserlaubnis after I come to Germany on new work visa?

Comment: This will depend on whether your new employment qualifies for a Blue Card.

Comment: Thank you, so let's suppose that it does qualify for a Blue Card, then an answer to my question is yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so let's suppose that it does qualify for a Blue Card, then an answer to my question is yes?

Yes, you must have a Blue Card to be eligable for the 33 months. Apply for a **Versicherungsverlauf** that shows this ([Versicherungsverlauf - Online-Dienste der Deutschen Rentenversicherung](https://www.eservice-drv.de/SelfServiceWeb/)). Take that with you, after your arrival in Germany, when you apply for the **residence permit** card. They should then issue a *Niederlassungserlaubnis* instead.